# Google Maps API View and populate issues with Gmaps4rails Gem in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, gmaps4rails

I am trying to follow [this tutorial here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R0l-7en3dUw&feature=youtu.be) to add a new scaffold to my app.  In the video, the model was called User but my model is called Reports.  I have made it to 4:14 but the map is not loading properly; [see here for screenshot.  It does not zoom in, only shows blue.  When I drag it one way or the other, it turns gray.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kZTY2.png)

I have followed along with the tutorial at this point precisely, but I am wondering if perhaps the scaffold is incompatible with my other models?  OR, is the bootstrap CSS template messing up the view of this map.

The problems are twofold--the view is not loading correctly, and the reports are not populating on the map.  I have pasted some of my source code below, let me know if you would like to see other files and thanks much for your help!

```
**reports_controller.rb**

class ReportsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_report, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /reports
  # GET /reports.json
  def index
    @reports = Report.all

    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@reports) do |report, marker|
      marker.lat report.latitude
      marker.lng report.longitude
      marker.infowindow report.description
    end
  end

  # GET /reports/1
  # GET /reports/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /reports/new
  def new
    @report = Report.new
  end

  # GET /reports/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /reports
  # POST /reports.json
  def create
    @report = Report.new(report_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.save
        format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @report }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /reports/1
  # PATCH/PUT /reports/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @report.update(report_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @report, notice: 'Report was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @report.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /reports/1
  # DELETE /reports/1.json
  def destroy
    @report.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to reports_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_report
      @report = Report.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def report_params
      params.require(:report).permit(:latitude, :longitude, :address, :description, :photo, :title, :text)
    end
end
```

-*-

```
**index.html.erb**

<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

<h1>Listing reports</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Latitude</th>
      <th>Longitude</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Photo</th>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Text</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @reports.each do |report| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= report.latitude %></td>
        <td><%= report.longitude %></td>
        <td><%= report.address %></td>
        <td><%= report.description %></td>
        <td><%= report.photo %></td>
        <td><%= report.title %></td>
        <td><%= report.text %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', report %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_report_path(report) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', report, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path %>

<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its very likely a css issue, nothing particular to gmaps4rails, just a known incompatibility between bootstrap and google maps, [see the gem doc](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Twitter-bootstrap-&-Foundation)

You'd need to add:

```
#map img { 
  max-width: none;
}
#map label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}
```

Comment: Where should I add this css, in my reports.css.scss file?  When I did this it improved the look a little bit but the function is still broken.

Comment: cant tell what your custom css changes, or maybe you have an error in your js.hard to figure out how to help, the gem itself works fine. Any public url?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294734/having-trouble-overriding-bootsrap-css-for-google-maps-api-accesssed-through-gma some more of my code and things I tried, thanks for the help.  I got this gem to work fine on a blank template, just bootstrap is giving issues it seems.

Comment: Search google maps + bootstrap issues: there is nothing particular to the gem

Comment: Yea, I have, but haven't found a good workaround.  Not sure where would be best to add the new code + what other pieces of code I would have to change.  My guess is javascript is throwing something off.