# Having trouble overriding bootstrap css for Google Maps API accessed through Gmaps4Rails Gem

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, twitter-bootstrap, gmaps4rails

I am following the Gmaps4Rails tutorial and trying to implement it in a bootstrap framework, but am having problems.  The map won't load correctly...  [See here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JiPfU.png)  Zooming in function does not work.

[I tried the workaround](https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Twitter-bootstrap-&-Foundation) but it has only helped marginally.  This appears to be a problem with how bootstrap is set up, or perhaps my require tree is not correct.  See below for my relevant code.

views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", media: "all",
                            "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application", 
                               "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>
    <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
      <%= content_tag(:div, value, class: "alert alert-#{key}") %>
    <% end %>
  </head>
```

...

custom.css.scss --> this is the main stylesheet for my app, and I added the workaround code here just to see if it would make a difference, but it did not.

```
@import "bootstrap";

/*MAP*/

#map img { 
  max-width: none;
}
#map label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}
```

...

application.css

```
...
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the top of the
 * compiled file, but it's generally better to create a new file per style scope.
 *
 *= require_self
 *= require_tree .
 */
```

index.html.erb --> home page where map is displayed

```
<head><link rel="stylesheet" href="reports.css.scss" /></head>

<script src="//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.14/src/markerclusterer_packed.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
<script src='//google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

...

<%= link_to 'New Report', new_report_path %>

<div style='width: 800px;'>
  <div id="map" style='width: 800px; height: 400px;'></div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
  markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
  handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
  handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

reports.css.scss --> The name of my model is Reports, as opposed to 'User' in the gmaps4rails demo

```
// Place all the styles related to the Reports controller here.
// They will automatically be included in application.css.
// You can use Sass (SCSS) here: http://sass-lang.com/



#map img { 
  max-width: none;
}
#map label { 
  width: auto; display:inline; 
}
```

application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem. Could you try using geolocation method and set the map centered on user's location. Check it its working.

```
if(navigator.geolocation)
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);

 function displayOnMap(position){
 var marker = handler.addMarker({
 lat: position.coords.latitude,
 lng: position.coords.longitude,
 picture: {
      url: "Keep Any Image",
      width:  36,
      height: 36
    },
    infowindow: "You"
});
handler.map.centerOn(marker);
}
```

**Updated answer**

*tweetsfromdb.html.erb*

```
<table class="table table-striped" style='width: 100%; display:none;' id="tweetstable" >
<tr><th>Picture</th>
<th>infowindow</th>
 <th>lat</th>
<th>lng</th></tr>
<% for tweet in @tweets %>
<tr>
<td> <%=tweet.profile_pic%> </td>
<td> <img src="<%=tweet.profile_pic%>" class="img-circle"/>
<%=tweet.tweet_text%>  <b><i>Location:<%=tweet.location%></i></td>
<td>  <%=tweet.lattitude%></td>
<td>  <%=tweet.longitude%></td>
 <% end %>
</table>
```

**The lattitude and longitude have been identified by geocoding the locations**

*script*
To Create the google maps

```
var handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
handler.buildMap({ internal: {id: 'map'} }, function(){
  if(navigator.geolocation)
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayOnMap);
});

function displayOnMap(position){
  var marker = handler.addMarker({
    lat: position.coords.latitude,
    lng: position.coords.longitude,
    picture: {
      url: "/images/pin_blue.png",
      width:  36,
      height: 36
    },
    infowindow: "You are here !"
  });
 handler.map.centerOn(marker);

}
```

**This script reads the data from the table and adds the markers**

```
 $("#googlemaps").click(function(){

  var array = [];
    var headers = [];
 $('#tweetstable th').each(function(index, item) {
    headers[index] = $(item).html();
});
$('#tweetstable tr').has('td').each(function() {
    var arrayItem = {};
    $('td', $(this)).each(function(index, item) {
        arrayItem[headers[index]] = $(item).html();
    });
    array.push(arrayItem);
});
handler.addMarkers(array);
handler.bounds.extendWith(array);
handler.fitMapToBounds();
});
```

Comment: Add this code in this code in the script tag of index.html.erb at the end of script. See [map example for this gem](http://apneadiving.github.io/) and see code for geolocation example.

Comment: Thanks, this got my map to display but the top right corner was still not displaying correctly.  My "reports" markers were also not populating on the map.

Comment: I am facing the same kind of problem with my project. My map has small rectangle visible on top left corner but it displays when you resize the browser u can try that. For populating markers, I have a workaround which works for me. I have added an onclick() for the  tabbed panel. I am displaying the data in a hidden table and then creating markers using jquery.